# How do I make an element inside ng-repeat to repeat just once?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hi I am stuck in a situation where I have to create a table such that for each Metaset I have to show rows of sets in a table. Ideally like Metaset should have a row span and the rows within it must span. Something like this 
Metaset1   SetAttr1 Setattr2
           Set Attr2 SetAttr2
Metaset2   SetAttr1 Setattr2
           Set Attr2 SetAttr2
I have used the following structure:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="(metaset, ids) in metasetHashMapTree">
                 <tr>
                    <td rowspan = "{{(ids.length*2) + 1}}"><span style="font-weight:bold">{{metaset}}</span></td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr ng-repeat="item in ids" >
                    <td width="10%" align="{{item.treeLevelStyle['align']}}"  bgcolor="{{item.treeLevelStyle['color']}}"> <span style="font-weight:{{item.treeLevelStyle['font-weight']}}">{{item.BuyId}}</span></td>
                    <td width="2%"  class="{{item['A-S0-a']}}"></td>
                    <td width="2%"  class="{{item['A-S0-b']}}"></td>
                    <td width="2%"  class="{{item['A-S0-c']}}"></td>
                    <td width="2%"  class="{{item['A-S0-d']}}"></td>
                    <td width="2%"  class="{{item['A-S0-e']}}"></td>
                    <td width="2%"  class="{{item['A-S0-f']}}"></td>
                    <td width="2%"  class="{{item['A-S0-g']}}"></td>
                    <td width="2%"  class="{{item['A-S1-a']}}"></td>
                    <td width="2%"  class="{{item['A-S1-b']}}"></td>
                    <td width="2%"  class="{{item['A-S2-a']}}"></td>
                    <td width="2%"  class="{{item['A-S3-a']}}"></td>
                    <td width="2%"  class="{{item['A-S4-a']}}"></td>
                    <td width="2%"  class="{{item['A-S5-a']}}"></td>
                    <td bgcolor="{{item.treeLevelStyle['color']}}"><span style="font-weight:{{item.treeLevelStyle['font-weight']}}">{{item.BuyTenant}}</span></td>
                    <td bgcolor="{{item.treeLevelStyle['color']}}"><span style="font-weight:{{item.treeLevelStyle['font-weight']}}">{{item.BuyRelease}}</span></td>
                    <td bgcolor="{{item.treeLevelStyle['color']}}"><span style="font-weight:{{item.treeLevelStyle['font-weight']}}">{{item.BuyComponentAffected}}</span></td>
                    <td bgcolor="{{item.treeLevelStyle['color']}}"><span style="font-weight:{{item.treeLevelStyle['font-weight']}}">{{item.BuyStatus}}</span></td>
                    <td font-weight : "{{item.treeLevelStyle['font-weight']}}" bgcolor="{{item.treeLevelStyle['color']}}"><span style="font-weight:{{item.treeLevelStyle['font-weight']}}">{{item.Match}}</span></td>
                    <td  bgcolor="{{item.treeLevelStyle['color']}}"><span style="font-weight:{{item.treeLevelStyle['font-weight']}}">{{item.SellDropFix}}</span></td>
                 </tr>
              </tbody>
```

I now have a requirement that only the first row within a metaset must show initially and the rest of them should show only after a click of a button on that metaset.

How do I modify thus structure to accpomodat ethat requirement. i have tried putting everything into one row and diabling to show metaset in teh second row like below, but the row lines appear as row span is now lost..

```
  <tbody ng-repeat="(metaset, ids) in metasetHashMapTree">
               <!--   <tr>
                    <td rowspan = "{{(ids.length*2) + 1}}"><span style="font-weight:bold">{{metaset}}</span></td>
                 </tr> -->
                 <tr ng-repeat="item in ids" >
                 <td> <span style="font-weight:bold">{{metaset}}</span></td>
                    <td width="10%" align="{{item.treeLevelStyle['align']}}"  bgcolor="{{item.treeLevelStyle['color']}}"> <span style="font-weight:{{item.treeLevelStyle['font-weight']}}">{{item.BuyId}}</span></td>
                    <td width="2%"  class="{{item['A-S0-a']}}"></td>
                    <td width="2%"  class="{{item['A-S0-b']}}"></td>
                    <td width="2%"  class="{{item['A-S0-c']}}"></td>
                    <td width="2%"  class="{{item['A-S0-d']}}"></td>
                    <td width="2%"  class="{{item['A-S0-e']}}"></td>
                    <td width="2%"  class="{{item['A-S0-f']}}"></td>
                    <td width="2%"  class="{{item['A-S0-g']}}"></td>
                    <td width="2%"  class="{{item['A-S1-a']}}"></td>
                    <td width="2%"  class="{{item['A-S1-b']}}"></td>
                    <td width="2%"  class="{{item['A-S2-a']}}"></td>
                    <td width="2%"  class="{{item['A-S3-a']}}"></td>
                    <td width="2%"  class="{{item['A-S4-a']}}"></td>
                    <td width="2%"  class="{{item['A-S5-a']}}"></td>
                    <td bgcolor="{{item.treeLevelStyle['color']}}"><span style="font-weight:{{item.treeLevelStyle['font-weight']}}">{{item.BuyTenant}}</span></td>
                    <td bgcolor="{{item.treeLevelStyle['color']}}"><span style="font-weight:{{item.treeLevelStyle['font-weight']}}">{{item.BuyRelease}}</span></td>
                    <td bgcolor="{{item.treeLevelStyle['color']}}"><span style="font-weight:{{item.treeLevelStyle['font-weight']}}">{{item.BuyComponentAffected}}</span></td>
                    <td bgcolor="{{item.treeLevelStyle['color']}}"><span style="font-weight:{{item.treeLevelStyle['font-weight']}}">{{item.BuyStatus}}</span></td>
                    <td font-weight : "{{item.treeLevelStyle['font-weight']}}" bgcolor="{{item.treeLevelStyle['color']}}"><span style="font-weight:{{item.treeLevelStyle['font-weight']}}">{{item.Match}}</span></td>
                    <td  bgcolor="{{item.treeLevelStyle['color']}}"><span style="font-weight:{{item.treeLevelStyle['font-weight']}}">{{item.SellDropFix}}</span></td>
                 </tr>
              </tbody>`
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo) you should use the LimitTo filter.

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in ids | limitTo:2" >
```

The limit amount can be specified in the controller or inserted directly into the filter.

Comment: Please mark this correct if you found this to be the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide/show elements, you can use the ngHide, or ngShow directives.

Check this [out](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow) for ngShow

Check this [out](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHide) for ngHide

The usage is relatively simple, example from the documentation:

```
 <!-- when $scope.myValue is truthy (element is hidden) -->
<div ng-hide="myValue" class="ng-hide"></div>

<!-- when $scope.myValue is falsy (element is visible) -->
<div ng-hide="myValue"></div>
```

The same applie to ngShow, except that when myValue is true, it will show.

Answer (score 0):

The rowspan can be calculated based on whether or not the details rows are visible or not.

Will use a variable `isVisible` that can be toggled within each `<tbody>` repeat since `ng-repeat` creates a child scope for each repeated element.

So the expression will set the `rowspan` to `1` when the rows are not visible and use your calculations when they are

```
<tr>
     <!-- rowspan will be "1" if not visible, or calculated if they are -->
     <td rowspan = "{{isVisible ? (ids.length*2) + 1 : 1}}">
         <span >{{metaset}}</span>
         <button ng-click="isvisible = !isVisible">Toggle Details</button>
     </td>
</tr>
```

Then use `ng-if` to toggle rows in dom

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in ids" ng-if="isVisible">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>  
        ........ 
</tr>
```

`ng-if` supports `ngAnimate` css animations so with a few css rules this could be made to act like a smooth accordion

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/FjQKTuHDab5oweUmSJ4C?p=preview)**</kbd>